# any reasons why my instansiated enemies prefabs don't appear in the camera game view even it apears in the scene view

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've got a really creepy issue, I am following a tutorial where making a monster chase game and instantiating enemies from the left and right side using an empty gameObject called Spawner got a script with an array that carries my monsters prefab to spawn randomly from the but unfortunately, the spawned monsters appear in the scene view but not in the camera view
here are some images that explain more
regards,

[image]

[image]

Comment: Could be the Z value. So that it is placed behind the wall. Try making everything else invisible and then part by part look where it is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if your `Z value` is within your Camera's [clipping plane](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-Camera.html).

Answer (score 1):

actually, i changed the camera position from -10 to -50 and then the enemy showed in the game view